# Echo content inside foreach only once

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo content inside a foreach once. At the moment, when a form is filled by the user, the message is displayed for every record skipped. If there are 35 records skipped, I will get 35 messages, because of the foreach. I want to avoid this, and be able to display only one echo for the entire results page. How can I do this? I suppose I may have to do this outside the foreach, but I have no clue how to take it out of the foreach.

```
foreach($allcourses as $course)
{
    if(Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
       if(Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student')
       {
           if($course->aircraft == '1')
           {
               echo '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
               continue; 
           }
           if($course->aircraft == '2')
           {
               echo '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
               continue; 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you must maintain the structure of that object, you could just have a boolean update if `$course->aircraft == 1` then echo accordingly:

```
$found = false;
foreach($allcourses as $course)
{
    if(Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
       if(Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student')
       {

           if($course->aircraft == '1')
           {
               $found = true;
           }
        }
    }
}
if($found)
{
    echo '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a simple flag variable in this case.

```
$warningEmitted = false;
```

Then, in your loop prior to emitting a warning:

```
if(!$warningEmitted) {
    // echo warning here. 
    $warningEmitted = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option would probably be to set your message as a variable, then echo the variable after the foreach is finished.

```
foreach($allcourses as $course)
{
    if(Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
        if(Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student')
        {
            if($course->aircraft == '1')
            {
                $message = '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
                continue; 
            }
        }
    }
}
if(isset($message))
{
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this does not return any records :( It's worth noting that I have couple of `if($course->aircraft == '1')`. I've updated the main message to show you what I mean.

Comment: If the $message variable is never set (i.e. The condition does not evaluate true) then it won't echo at all. This is probably the case in your test, unless you are un-setting the $message variable from within your foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Outside the loop assume `$count=1;`

Inside the loop, you can put an if statement.

```
if($count==1) { $count++; echo "Whatever";}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a boolean variable which you set to false initially, and the set it to true in the loop if you get a match.

Then you can check the boolean after the loop has finished to decide if you need to display the message or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create additional variable in which you will store information whether the message was already displayed or not. When you display it, set the var to true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, I think you want to use 'break' to stop looping as soon as a problem is found.

```
if (Auth::LoggedIn() && Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student') {
    foreach ($allcourses as $course) {
        if ($course->aircraft == '1') {
            echo '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
            break; 
        }
        if ($course->aircraft == '2') {
            echo '<div class="msg-red">Some lessons could not be found, because you may not be entitled to view/book them at this stage of your course.</div><br/>';
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Above I've also moved the "if logged in" conditional to be outside the loop (so it's only checked once).

Something to consider:

A more user friendly approach might to add each error into an array - instead of using echo & breaking out - and then loop through that error array at the end, showing with more information about the error so they can be corrected all at once by the end user (depending on how your form works, of course).

Comment: Won't the use of `break` stop the results from being shown? Below the ifs, I have a table row for each `$course` that is returned.

Comment: Break stops the current loop (and continues after the loop). If you have code you've not disclosed here also in the loop then you would benefit from a different solution probably - I can't guess though, you need to give more info.